# How find this limit $I=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)^{\cot^2{x}}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit of the value

> $$I=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)^{\cot^2{x}},(0<a\neq1,0<b\neq 1,a\neq b)$$

**Following is My ugly methods**

> $$I=e^{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\cot^2{x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)}}$$
>   so we only find following this limit
>   $$A=\lim_{x\to 0}\cot^2{x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{a^x-x\ln{a}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}\right)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln{(a^x-x\ln{a})}-\ln{(b^x-x\ln{b})}}{x^2}$$

By the  **L'Hospital**
$$A=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{a^x\ln{a}-\ln{a}}{a^x-x\ln{a}}-\dfrac{b^x\ln{b}-\ln{b}}{b^x-x\ln{b}}}{2x}$$
so

> \begin{align*}A&=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{a^xb^x(\ln{a}-\ln{b})+\ln{a}\ln{b}x(b^x-a^x)+a^x\ln{b}-b^x\ln{a}}{(a^x-x\ln{a})(b^x-x\ln{b})(2x)}\\
> &=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(\ln{a}-\ln{b})+\ln{a}\ln{b}x(b^x-a^x)+(\ln{b}-\ln{a})}{2x}\\
> &=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln{a}\ln{b} x(b^x-a^x)}{2x}\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}

so $$I=e^{0}=1$$

**Have other nice methods and my result is true? Thank you**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\ln (a^x-x\ln{a}) = \ln (1+\frac{x^2}{2}(\ln{a})^2 + o(x^2)) = \frac{x^2}{2}(\ln{a})^2 + o(x^2)$, $\ln (b^x-x\ln{b}) = \frac{x^2}{2}(\ln{b})^2 + o(x^2)$, we have
$$\cot^2{x} \left(\ln (a^x-x\ln{a}) - \ln (b^x-x\ln{b}\right) = \frac{(\ln{a})^2-(\ln{b})^2}{2} + o(1).$$
Hence

> $$I = \sqrt{e^{(\ln{a})^2-(\ln{b})^2}}.$$